# Pollable signalling between threads

Tags: c++, c, unix

I'm working on a project, where a primary server thread needs to dispatch events to a series of worker threads. The work that goes on in the worker threads relies on polling (ie. epoll or kqueue depending on the UNIX system in question) with timeouts on these operations needing to be handles. This means, that a normal conditional variable or semaphore structure is not viable for this dispatch, as it would make one or the other block resulting in an unwanted latency between either handling the events coming from polling or the events originating from the server thread.

So, I'm wondering what the most optimal construct for dispatching such events between threads in a pollable fashion is? Essentially, all that needs to be delivered is a pollable "signal" that tells the worker thread, that it has more events to fetch. I've looked at using UNIX pipes (unnamed ones, as it's internal to the process) which seems like a decent solution given that a single byte can be written to the pipe and read back out when the queue is cleared -- but, I'm wondering if this is the best approach available? Or the fastest?

Alternatively, there is the possibility to use signalfd(2) on Linux, but as this is not available on BSD systems, I'd rather like to avoid this construct. I'm also wondering how great the overhead in using system signals actually is?

Comment: Where will the threads be getting data from? I am sorry if I am misunderstanding the question, but what is wrong with simply polling whatever input source the thread would read with a poll(2) call?

Comment: I reread your question a few times and I'm still a little fuzzy on what you're asking... it sounds like the worker threads have some dead time (waiting on a pipe or something) and... that's where I'm lost. Why is the dead time relevant? Don't you just want to wait for them to complete their work anyway?

Comment: Apparently my explanation just got deleted, so here goes. The worker thread deals with both socket I/O and asynchronous disk I/O, which means that it is optimally always waiting for the event queuing mechanism (epoll/kqueue). The problem is, that new tasks are also handed off to the thread, but as these tasks are not necessarily relying on I/O I can't simply just throw them in the event loop of the specific worker thread.

So, I have to find a way to notify the worker in this event polling loop, that new app events are available to be handled. Otherwise I'd be wasting time on one or the other.

Comment: As you were thinking, using a pipe is a good option.  You can just add its read end to the group of file descriptors you're waiting on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan Hudec's answer is correct, although I wouldn't recommend using signals for a few reasons:

- Older versions of glibc emulated `pselect` and `ppoll` in a non-atomic fashion, making them basically worthless. Even when you used the mask correctly, signals could get "lost" between the `pthread_sigprocmask` and `select` calls, meaning they don't cause `EINTR`.
- I'm not sure `signalfd` is any more efficient than the pipe. (Haven't tested it, but I don't have any particular reason to believe it is.)
- signals are generally a pain to get right. I've spent a lot of effort on them (see [my sigsafe library](http://www.slamb.org/projects/sigsafe/)) and I'd recommend avoiding them if you can.

Since you're trying to have asynchronous handling portable to several systems, I'd recommend looking at libevent. It will abstract `epoll` or `kqueue` for you, and it will even wake up workers on your behalf when you add a new event. See [event.c](http://levent.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=levent/libevent;a=blob;f=event.c;h=66fbfd588c62cf6a03932de776331379af42dc31;hb=HEAD)

```
2058 static inline int
2059 event_add_internal(struct event *ev, const struct timeval *tv,
2060     int tv_is_absolute)
2061 {
...
2189         /* if we are not in the right thread, we need to wake up the loop */
2190         if (res != -1 && notify && EVBASE_NEED_NOTIFY(base))
2191                 evthread_notify_base(base);
...
2196 }
```

Also,

> The worker thread deals with both socket I/O and asynchronous disk I/O, which means that it is optimally always waiting for the event queuing mechanism (epoll/kqueue).

You're likely to be disappointed here. These event queueing mechanisms don't really support asynchronous disk I/O. See [this recent thread](http://archives.seul.org/libevent/users/Sep-2011/msg00018.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the input on the signal vs. pipe decision. In terms of polling mechanisms, I've implemented them from the ground up to get away with using POSIX AIO libraries, so that's no biggie, but thanks on the heads up -- although in my experience, [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) is somewhat better for specific things. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As far as performance goes, the cost of system call is comparably huge to other operations, so it's the number of system calls that matters. There are two options:

1. Use the pipes as you wrote. If you have any useful payload for the message, you get one system call to send, one system call to wait and one system call to receive. Try to pass any relevant data down the pipe instead of reading them from a shared structure to avoid additional overhead from locking.
2. The `select` and `poll` have variants, that also waits for signals (`pselect`, `ppoll`). Linux `epoll` can do the same using `signalfd`, so it remains a question whether `kqueue` can wait for signals, which I don't know. If it can, than you could use them (you are using different mechanism on Linux and *BSD anyway). It would save you the syscall for reading if you don't have good use for the passed data.

I would expect passing the data over socket to be more efficient if it allows you do do away with any other locking.